# Centering the map on points on the map

Tags: javascript, html

I have small problem with Open Street Map.
I have this code:

```
function onLocationFound(e) {
            var radius = e.accuracy / 2;
            lat = e.latlng.lat;
            lng = e.latlng.lng;

            L.marker(e.latlng).addTo(map).bindPopup("Tutaj jesteś!!!");
            //L.circle(e.latlng, radius).addTo(map);


        }

        function onLocationError(e) {
            //alert(e.message);
            console.log(e.message);
        }


        var map = L.map('mapdiv', {
            editable: true,
            fadeAnimation: false
        }).setView([54.35070881441067, 18.641191756395074], 15);
        L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        // L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
            maxZoom: 16, zoomControl: true, detectRetina: true
        }).addTo(map);


        map.on('locationfound', onLocationFound);
        map.on('locationerror', onLocationError);
        map.locate({setView: true, maxZoom: 16});


        let myFilter = ['grayscale:100%'];

        let myTileLayer = L.tileLayer.colorFilter('https://maps.wikimedia.org/osm-intl/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: '<a href="https://wikimediafoundation.org/wiki/Maps_Terms_of_Use">Wikimedia</a>',
            filter: myFilter,
        }).addTo(map);




        var LeafIcon = L.Icon.extend({
            options: {
                iconSize: [25, 29],
                iconAnchor: [25, 29],
                popupAnchor: [-12, -22]
            }
        });


        L.icon = function (options) {
            return new L.Icon(options);
        };


        var icons = {
            greenIcon: new LeafIcon({iconUrl: '{{asset('assets/images/ikon19.png')}}'}),
            redIcon: new LeafIcon({iconUrl: '{{asset('assets/images/ikon20.png')}}'}),
            blackIcon: new LeafIcon({iconUrl: '{{asset('assets/images/ikon20.png')}}'})
        }


        var image = '';
        $.ajax({
            url: '{{url('/getPointForMap')}}',
            method: 'get',
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(JSON.parse(data), function(i, poi) {
                    if (poi.photo != ''){
                        image = '<img src="'+poi.photo+'" class="mapImgF"><br/>';
                    }
                    L.marker([poi.lat, poi.lng], {icon: icons[poi.marker]}).addTo(map).addTo(map).bindPopup('<a href="'+poi.url+'">' + image + '<div class="mapTitleF">' + poi.name + '</div>' + '<div class="mapDescF"> ocena: ' + poi.score + '<br/>' + poi.price + ' </div></a>', {maxWidth: "auto", closeOnClick: true});
                });
            }
        });

<div id="mapdiv"></div>
```

The map generally works correctly, downloads and displays points.

My problem is the zoom setting. After starting the map, the user is asked for permission to locate. After agreeing the map is loaded, however, the maximum zoom of the map zoom is set. I would like the zoom to be as low as possible, so that there is a visible fragment of the map in which the user is located.

How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the key to your problem is this line: `map.locate({setView: true, maxZoom: 16});`

The `maxZoom` parameter here determines what is the maximum zoom that should be automatically set when displaying user's location (it doesn't mean this is the maximum zoom user can use on the map, it only refers to the automatic view setting). So if you change it to `map.locate({setView: true, maxZoom: 8});` you should see the difference.

Here's the respective documentation if you want to dig into it more: https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.5.0.html#locate-options-maxzoom

Comment: Thx - it's help, but now I here this problem: https://ibb.co/wWQHP6d (grey background)

Comment: I'm not sure if that helps, but you can try to change the default zoom you use before locating the user: `.setView([54.35070881441067, 18.641191756395074], 15);` try changing the `15` to the same zoom level as you use in `locate` function.

Comment: it's not help :(